# Why are computer keyboard keys printed in Uppercase?

Tags: keyboard, typography

Although many users mostly type lowercase letters, why are all keyboards printed with uppercase letters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess it's because uppercase letters are both more distinctive and recognizable. Compare, for example, lowercase 'i' vs 'l' and 'I' vs 'L'. It has no effect for power users but important for newbies I believe.

Comment: And yet, many children's early learning keyboards have lower case letters on! [For example these images on Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=keyboard+with+lowercase+letters&sa=X&es_sm=93&biw=1745&bih=865&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=C4WVU_L0AsOyPO6MgPgJ&ved=0CGUQsAQ)

Comment: @RogerAttrill interesting, maybe it's because children have to train to recognize lowercase letters more than uppercase so it's a kind of training too.

Comment: Alexeypegov: May not be so much about more training needed. It may be more to do with how we teach children to read: that always starts with lowercase letters. The famous "leesplank" (board used in reading lessons), avoided the distinguishability problem by not having words that mixed characters that are hard to distinguish from each other. @RogerAttrill

Comment: This is absolutely false. Lowercase characters (when properly rendered) have been proven many times over to be more recognizeable and clearly more distinctive. Sometimes convention trumps common sense.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's partly alexeypegov's answer of distinctiveness, but also historical reasons.  The [first typewriters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholes_and_Glidden_typewriter#QWERTY_keyboard), which also had the first QWERTY keyboard, only supported upper case letters.